# mysql_affected_rows() returns 0 for UPDATE statement even when an update actually happens

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the number of rows affected in a simple mysql update query.  However, when I run this code below, PHP's mysql_affected_rows() always equals 0.  No matter if foo=1 already (in which case the function **should correctly** return 0, since no rows were changed), or if foo currently equals some other integer (in which case the function should return 1).

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE myTable SET foo=1 WHERE bar=2";
mysql_query($updateQuery);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo "affected!";
}
else {
    echo "not affected"; // always prints not affected
}
```

The UPDATE statement itself works.  The INT gets changed in my database.  I have also double-checked that the database connection isn't being closed beforehand or anything funky.  Keep in mind, mysql_affected_rows doesn't necessarily require you to pass a connection link identifier, though I've tried that too.

Details on the function: [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the record is being updated? Make sure you set foo equal to something other than 1 before you run the test.

Comment: By any chance, could your page be called twice, like because of a rewrite rule perhaps? This would cause the data to be updated the first time, and then not the second time when you see the final output... Wouldn't hurt to check your web server logs.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's actually returning 0 and not a negative value?

Comment: adding onto what @Michael said instead of echo try putting `die("affected");`  That might get it to work before the double rewrite if that is whats happening.

Comment: Ahhhh... you won't believe it, but the page was actually loading ten times in succession via an AJAX call and I was only looking at the callback from the last call.  That was a dumb move.  What a way to start out on Stack Overflow, huh? :)  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Alex, make sure you put in your solution and describe the actual problem with how you fixed it so that others can use it.  Glad you found the problem.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.  You can then select it as correct and close out this question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll never understand this community.. 8 upvotes for a question claiming `mysql_affected_rows()` was broken...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_affected\_rows gives "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource" error WITH VALID QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078164/mysql-affected-rows-gives-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource)

Answer (score 23):

Newer versions of MySQL are clever enough to see if modification is done or not. Lets say you fired up an UPDATE Statement:

```
UPDATE tb_Employee_Stats SET lazy = 1 WHERE ep_id = 1234
```

Lets say if the Column's Value is already 1; then no update process occurs thus **mysql_affected_rows()** will return 0; else if Column lazy had some other value rather than 1, then 1 is returned. There is no other possibilities except for human errors.

Comment: So that was it, making my life difficult. Now I can update my code to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

The following notes will be helpful for you,

mysql_affected_rows() returns

- +0: a row wasn't updated or inserted (likely because the row already existed, 
  but no field values were actually changed during the UPDATE).
- +1: a row was inserted
- +2: a row was updated
- -1: in case of error.

[mysqli affected rows developer notes](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the MySQL function `ROW_COUNT` directly?

```
mysql_query('UPDATE myTable SET foo = 1 WHERE bar = 2');
if(mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT ROW_COUNT()'), 0, 0)) {
  print "updated";
}
else {
  print "no updates made";
}
```

More information on the use of `ROW_COUNT` and the other MySQL information functions is at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_affected_rows requires you to pass the reference to your database connection as the only parameter, instead of the reference to your mysqli query. eg.

```
$dbref=mysqli_connect("dbserver","dbusername","dbpassword","dbname");

$updateQuery = mysqli_query($dbref,"UPDATE myTable SET foo=1 WHERE bar=2");

echo mysqli_affected_rows($dbref);
```

NOT

```
echo mysqli_affected_rows($updateQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting like this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(...,...,...);
```

and then call like this

```
if(mysql_affected_rows($connection) > 0)
    echo "affected";
} else { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try something else in update then foo=1. Put something totaly different then you wil see is it updating or not without if loop. then if it does, your if loop should work.

Answer (score 0):

You work this?

```
$timestamp=mktime();
$updateQuery = "UPDATE myTable SET foo=1, timestamp={$timestamp} WHERE bar=2";
mysql_query($updateQuery);

$updateQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE timestamp={$timestamp}";
$res=mysql_query($updateQuery);
$row=mysql_fetch_row($res);
if ($row[0]>0) {
    echo "affected!";
}
else {
    echo "not affected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because mySql is checking whether the field made any change or not, 
To over come this, I created a new TINY field 'DIDUPDATE' in the table.

added this to your query 'DIDUPDATE=DIDUPDATE*-1'

it looks like.

```
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE myTable SET foo=1, DIDUPDATE=DIDUPDATE*-1  WHERE bar=2";
    mysql_query($updateQuery);

    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) 
    {
            echo "affected!";
    }
    else 
    {
            echo "not affected"; 
    }
```

it works fine!!!

Answer (score -1):

Was My Tought !

I was just about to tell to check if the function's being called many times !

Just a little advice:

try using isset() & POST / GET or something like that;

```
if ( isset( $_POST['Update'] == 'yes' ) ) :

// your code goes here ...

endif;
```

Hope it was clear and useful, Ciao :)

Comment: You cannot use isset() on the result of an expression.