# mysql_affected_rows gives "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource" error WITH VALID QUERY

Tags: mysql

This question has been posted 50 times, and the answer is always "your query has an error". Well, **my query is valid** and my database is updated with values and I'm still having trouble with mysql_affected rows. My simplified code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE t_users
    SET t_users.facebookID = '$facebookID'
    WHERE t_users.username = '$username'";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

if ($query){
  if (mysql_affected_rows($query)) echo "success";
}
else echo "error registering account--error was " . mysql_error();
```

When I run this, the facebookID column is updated, but I get a warning:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource...
```

Any ideas what else to check?

Comment: Have you tried running `gettype` or `var_dump` on `$query` after `mysql_query` and before `mysql_affected_rows`?

Comment: Yes, "var_dump($query);" echoes "bool(true)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

The argument to [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) should be a resource returned by `mysql_connect`, 
not a resource returned by `mysql_query`. Or it could be omitted entirely.

Comment: I could have SWORN I tried omitting it before (mysql_affected_rows() instead of mysql_affected_rows($query)) but I tried again and it worked. Thanks!