# UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE SQL Query Failing

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to sort out a query on a web app that I'm making, which keeps failing and I have no idea why! The code is below:

```
$update = $_GET['update'];
if($update == "true"){
    $setDetails="UPDATE users SET email='{$_POST['email']}', api_key='{$_POST['api_key']}', api_secret='{$_POST['api_secret']}' WHERE username={$_POST['username']}";
    if(mysql_query($setDetails)){
        $updatemsg = '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Success!</strong> Your details have been updated in our database.</div>';
    }else{
        $updatemsg = '<div class="alert alert-error"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Failure!</strong> Your details could not be updated in our database. Please try again later or contact us if this keeps happening.</div>';
    }
}else if($update == "false"){
    $updatemsg = '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Success!</strong> Your changed were discarded.</div>';
}
```

Any idea's, help or tips? Note that further down my web app I have `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'` which works fine so there is no issue with the database connection.

Comment: What do you mean by failing? Do you get an SQL error? Please also note, that you did not escape your username, making SQL Injection possible.

Comment: Among other SQL injection-related things, you should quote that `username=$_POST['username']` field at the end.

Comment: @Chris I know about the security issues, I plan to fix them next. What happens is that $updatemsg returns the second value (The error message).

Comment: if(mysql_query($setDetails)){ is not the right way to check if update was successfull; u shud use mysql_affected_rows(). But while using it there are some precautions required. Check here for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397291/mysql-affected-rows-returns-0-for-update-statement-even-when-an-update-actuall/9871672#9871672

Comment: @JimmySawczuk That fixed it, thanks. If you want to post an answer I would be more than happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BenedictLewis Irfan DANISH covered it pretty well, he can keep the accept. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$update = $_GET['update'];
if($update == "true"){
    $setDetails="UPDATE users SET email='{$_POST['email']}', api_key='{$_POST['api_key']}', api_secret='{$_POST['api_secret']}' WHERE username='{$_POST['username']}'";
    if(mysql_query($setDetails)){
        $updatemsg = '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Success!</strong> Your details have been updated in our database.</div>';
    }else{
        $updatemsg = '<div class="alert alert-error"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Failure!</strong> Your details could not be updated in our database. Please try again later or contact us if this keeps happening.</div>';
    }
}else if($update == "false"){
    $updatemsg = '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Success!</strong> Your changed were discarded.</div>';
}
```

**Details:**
Your code:

```
$setDetails="UPDATE users SET email='{$_POST['email']}', api_key='{$_POST['api_key']}', api_secret='{$_POST['api_secret']}' WHERE username={$_POST['username']}";
```

Correct Code:

```
 $setDetails="UPDATE users SET email='{$_POST['email']}', api_key='{$_POST['api_key']}', api_secret='{$_POST['api_secret']}' WHERE username='{$_POST['username']}'";
```

**Missing ' around username string.**

Comment: I cannot accept the answer for another 5 minutes, you must wait 10 minutes after asking your question to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: This suggested solution is not safe from injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.Put quotes for the `username`

```
$setDetails="UPDATE users 
            SET email='{$_POST['email']}', 
                api_key='{$_POST['api_key']}', 
                api_secret='{$_POST['api_secret']}' 
            WHERE username='{$_POST['username']}' ";
```

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to they are **deprecated**.Instead use `mysqli_*` statements or `PDO` statements

Comment: This suggested solution is not safe from injection attacks.